# Android GCM 7.5, not receiving data

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I was updating my app to new GCM 7.5 while I noticed thatgoogle changed lot of things.
take a look at my code

```
public class GcmIntentService extends GcmListenerService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

public GcmIntentService() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    String message2 = data.getString("payload");
    String title = data.getString("title");
    String type = data.getString("push_type");
    Log.i(TAG, "Message: " + message2 + " PushType:" + type + "title" + title);
    for (String key : data.keySet())
    {
        Log.d("Bundle Debug", key + " = \"" + data.get(key) + "\"");
    }
    //   parseMessage(data);
    // sendNotification(message);
}

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {
    // sendNotification("Deleted messages on server");
}

@Override
public void onMessageSent(String msgId) {
    //   sendNotification("Upstream message sent. Id=" + msgId);
}

@Override
public void onSendError(String msgId, String error) {
    // sendNotification("Upstream message send error. Id=" + msgId + ", error" + error);
}
```

Now into my problem: The data recieved is null except I logged the bundle there was a collapsekey too.

Manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.was.abcd"
android:versionCode="404080000"
android:versionName="4.8.0" >

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<!-- * Google Cloud Messaging -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.was.abcd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.was.abcd.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- Google Cloud Messaging * -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="@bool/largeheap"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FullScreen" >

    <!-- * Google Cloud Messaging -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- Google Cloud Messaging * -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.magazine.screens.ShelfActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magazine.screens.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magazine.screens.ReaderActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magazine.screens.PurchaseActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magazine.screens.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/fb_logo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <!-- * Google Cloud Messaging -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.was.abcd" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magazine.messaging.NotificationDialogActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="com.magazine.messaging.GcmIntentService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: have you written necessary permission in AndroidManifest.xml like c2dm and other.

Comment: I guess. Added my manifest.xml

Comment: Can you refer this sample https://github.com/google/gcm as i have not tried new GCM framework yet and your code seems to be new one.

Comment: btw I tested using http://gcm-alert.appspot.com/ ,I don't have access to the server.

Comment: Have a look at this sample https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm it shows both sides of GCM.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these points:

- As per Google Documentation make use of `GCMReceiver` instead of `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.
- Also if you are using gcm.register() please make us of `InstanceId` as the former has been deprecated.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Here is a goof reference as well https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services